# Spark sql creating and referencing a mapping / lookup table like Qlik's applymap function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I am working in an Azure Synapse spark sql notebook I have a lookup table that contains the display values for 15 code fields in a main table. I want to avoid having to join the lookup table to the main table 15 times to lookup the display value for each code field.

In Qlik scripting I would load the lookup table into memory as a two-column mapping table and then I would be able to use the applymap() function in the field expressions to retrieve the display value.

Is there an equivalent in SparkSQL that I can use?

Example:

table 1 : reference table containing display values for code fields in the transaction table

| field | code | display_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| status | O | Open |
| status | C | Closed |
| stage | N | Not Started |
| stage | I | In Progress |
| stage | C | Completed |

Table 2: transaction table

| transaction_id | status | stage | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | O | N | 100 |
| 10002 | O | I | 110 |
| 10003 | C | C | 200 |

Required Results:

| transaction_id | status | stage | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Open | Not Started | 100 |
| 10002 | Open | In Progress | 110 |
| 10003 | Closed | Completed | 200 |

In reality there could be 20+ columns that need mapping/lookups so creating views and doing joins is not a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Spark SQL user-defined function (UDF) to retrieve the display value from the lookup table and fill the field in the main tables. This way, we can avoid using `join` for all tables.

**Sample User defined function:**

This is the user defined function which takes the `input_value` as input and returns the `display_value` as output from the lookup table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_display_value(input_value STRING)
RETURNS STRING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE display_value STRING;
  SET display_value = (SELECT display_value FROM lookup_table WHERE input_value = input_value);
  RETURN display_value;
END;
```

You can use `get_display_value(<column_name>)` in the queries to get the lookup table value along with the main table value.

Comment: That is the MS Co-Pilot answer word for word. It does not consider Synapse's environment and you are not encouraged to create permanent udfs in the lake databases. I was hoping for a solution that can be contained within the synapse notebook.

Comment: 1) UDF is written in spark -sql in synapse environment only.
2) Can you put more details with sample input data and output data.

Comment: example added to original question above